# Why am I getting "use of parameter 'N' outside of function body"?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to overload the `[]` operator so I can have access to the elements of a `std::tuple`. For some reason I am getting the following errors:

> prog.cpp:11:73: error: use of parameter ‘N’ outside function body
>   prog.cpp:11:73: error: use of parameter ‘N’ outside function body
>   prog.cpp:11:73: error: use of parameter ‘N’ outside function body
>   prog.cpp:11:89: error: template argument 1 is invalid

Pretty weird since most of them are repetitions of the first. And I don't understand why I am getting that error because isn't the whole point of having late return-type is so that we can use parameter for the return-type?

```
#include <tuple>

template <class... Args>
struct type_list
{
    std::tuple<Args...> var;

    type_list(Args&&... args) : var(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    auto operator[](std::size_t const N) -> typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>>::type&&
    {
        return std::get<N>(var);
    }
};

int main()
{
    type_list<int, int, bool> array(2, 4, true);
}
```

If anyone can explain why this is happening and how I can get this to work it would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just think about what you're asking for, for a minute.  You expect the *type* of a function to change depending on the (runtime-varying) *value* you pass to it?  That may fly in an untyped scripting language, but not in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use the function argument `N` from `operator[]` (which isn't known at compile time) as a template argument for `std::tuple_element` which must be known at compile time.

Comment: Why can't it be known at compile time?

Comment: @templateboy: Because I can write `size_t i; cin >> i; cout << yourobject[i];`  Which `operator<<` overload should the compiler use there?

Comment: Is there any way to make the parameter `constexpr`?

Answer (score 2):

The template argument `N` is a compile-time thing, while the `operator[]` argument `N` only materializes at runtime. The compiler doesn't know what `N` is, so it cannot make sense of it as a template argument.